# logical "OR" between bin files

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that take a list of files and perform a "logical or" between them. As you can see in the script, at the first stage i'm creating an empty `append_buffer`. Then I want to do a logical OR with all the files in the list.

My problem is that when I read the files I get a `str` and not a bytearray. So when I tried to perform the `or` it failed. I have tried to convert it without any success.

```
        import struct
        #import sys, ast

        buffera = bytearray()
        append_buffer = bytearray()
        output_buffer = bytearray()

        files_list=['E:\out.jpg','E:\loala2.jpg','E:\Koala.jpg','E:\loala2.jpg']
        print(files_list[1])


        #######################################################################################################################
        # create_dummy_bin_file_for_first_iteration , base on first file size
        temp_file = open(files_list[1], "rb")
        print ( temp_file )
        buffera = temp_file.read(temp_file.__sizeof__())
        temp_file.close()

        for x in range(0, len(buffera)):
            append_buffer.append(0x00)
        #######################################################################################################################

        for i in range(1, len(files_list)):
            print( files_list[i] )
            file = open(files_list[i], "rb")
            file_buffer = file.read(file.__sizeof__())
            file.close()

            if ( len(file_buffer) != len(append_buffer) ):
                print("Can't merge different size bin files ")
                exit(1)
            else:

                for x in range(0, len(buffera)):
                    or_data=(file_buffer[x] | append_buffer[x])
                    print("---")
                    print(type(file_buffer[x]))
                    print(file_buffer[x])

                    print("---")
                    print(type(append_buffer[x]))
                    print(append_buffer[x])



        outputfile = open(files_list[0], "wb")
        outputfile.write(output_buffer)
        outputfile.close()
```

Comment: Read them byte by byte, perform or, and write to the output buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example makes the complete work in memory.

```
# Read data from the first file
with open("file1.txt", "rt") as f:
    d1 = f.read()

# Read data from the second file
with open("file2.txt", "rt") as f:
    d2 = f.read()

# Make sure that both sizes are equal
assert len(d1) == len(d2)

# Calculate OR-ed data
d3 = "".join(chr(ord(d1[i]) | ord(d2[i])) for i in range(len(d1)))

# Write the output data
with open("file3.txt", "wt") as f:
    f.write(d3)
```

It's possible to process these data byte-by-byte too, in order to reduce memory consumption.

Comment: Save some memory by omitting the brackets inside the join in `d3 = ... `, you can use a generator expression instead of actually constructing the list.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy You are right, of course. I am sorry for this omission. It's fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ord` and `chr` operators to do convert each character to an integer and back.

Using this, your code would be:

```
or_data=chr(ord(file_buffer[x]) | ord(append_buffer[x]))
```

Comment: Don’t you think reading them byte by byte would use much less memory?